# Torque due to external forces only

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque, rotation

Suppose two parallel lines L1 and L2 at a separation of 100 metre .
Suppose two charged particles are moving with constant and equal speeds , the first one on L1 and other on L2 ; and their direction of motion is toward each other . Initially , they were very far and after some time = t , they are at significant separation .

Now , suppose these two charges as system . Also suppose that after some time , due to electromagnetic force and initial non-zero velocity , these charges exhibit a circular motion ( their centre of mass being at rest ) and their relative position being at diametrically opposite points on the circle .

My question is that how the system starts rotation even though there is no net external force as well as no any individual external force. I have been taught that only external forces ( even though their resultant can be zero ) should create torque ? And in this case , there are no external forces as well as no net external force because force due to charge is internal . ( Similar situation as of binary star systems )

Comment: Your assumptions are difficult to relate to real physical phenomena. It already starts by the fact that the two lines are what: electrical wires?, geometric lines?. Are they parallel to each other or perpendicularly aligned? What are systems? Massive bodies that are electrically charged?

Comment: System is those charges , spherically shaped with small diameters . The parallel lines are only described to describe the initial direction of motion of charges .

Comment: I only wanted to know that the statement " no torque and hence no rotation can be produced due to internal forces only " is always correct?

Comment: If it still looks not good , then I'll edit question with a better demonstration to deliver my actual question .